# Android :: determine status of 3G network on widget adding / removal

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-networking

I created simple widget which is aimed to show current status of mobile network connection (see the source code http://tinyurl.com/cmucqr6)

So far it works well, the only problem is sometimes it doesn't show the correct status of the network (so it can show it enabled when it's actually disabled and vise versa). But it correctly disables the network if it's enabled, and enables it if it's disabled. So I think that something is wrong with my update widget image code.

Can somebody please explain what might be wrong there? May be I need to subscribe to some specific event like network_enable or similar?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I posted link to github in the question, the source is quite long to paste it here.